# Is there a SAS function for removing respondents who are missing values for one question?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to run analysis on a data set relating to a particular variable, but the question was only asked to half the respondents of the survey. Is there a function in SAS that would allow me to make a new data set from the current data set, but only including those who responded to the question of interest?

Comment: You need to provide more information on how your data is structured.  Also what attempts have you made and in what way did they not work?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to describe the structure of my data set, but I tried this :

Comment: data new;
 set old;
 if varofinterest =. then delete;
 run;

Comment: Your example should work if each respondent has only one observation. Also if the variable is character instead of numeric then your test is wrong.  You can use the MISSING() function instead as it will work for either variable type.

Comment: I tried using MISSING() and it worked. Must have been a character based variable. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also be aware of that Missing(a) does not just the same as a=. or a=" " for numeric variables there are different kind of missing and only one is equal to '.' . Knowing the structure of data is very importend for SAS programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
data responded_Question_42;
  set survey_responses;
  where not missing(Answer_42);
run;
```

You can also use the where clause directly at the time of analysis, for example:

```
Proc FREQ data=survey_responses;
  where not missing(Answer_42);
  table Answer_42 Answer_43 Answer_44;
run;
```