# Is there a SAS function to delete negative and missing values from a variable in a dataset?

Tags: sas

Variable name is PRC. This is what I have so far. First block to delete negative values. Second block is to delete missing values.

```
data work.crspselected;
  set work.crspraw;
  where crspyear=2016;
  if (PRC < 0)
    then delete;
  where ticker = 'SKYW';
run;

data work.crspselected;
  set work.crspraw;
  where ticker = 'SKYW';
  where crspyear=2016;
  where=(PRC ne .) ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a function to remove negative and missing values, it can be done more simply when inputting or outputting the data. It can also be done with only one data step:

```
data work.crspselected;
set work.crspraw(where = (PRC >= 0 & PRC ^= .)); * delete values that are negative and missing;
where crspyear = 2016;
where ticker = 'SKYW';
run;
```

The section that does it is:

```
(where = (PRC >= 0 & PRC ^= .))
```

Which can be done for either the input dataset `(work.crspraw)` or the output dataset `(work.crspselected)`.

If you must use a function, then the function `missing()` includes only missing values [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691248/is-there-a-sas-function-for-removing-respondents-who-are-missing-values-for-one). Hence `^missing()` would do the opposite and include only non-missing values. There is not a function for non-negative values. But I think it's easier and quicker to do both together simultaneously without a function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need more than your first test to remove negative **and missing values**. SAS treats all 28 missing values (., ._, .A ... .Z) as less than any actual number.